# How to have all platform compiler output the same string for NaN?

Tags: c++, nan, ostream

Consider this code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
}
```

When compiled with Visual Studio 2010, output is `1.#QNAN`. When compiled with g++, output is `nan`. Note that Visual Studio 2015 outputs "nan".

However, I need both to produce the same output. What's the most simple way to do that? I tried to override `operator<<` for `double` but I feel like that's not the right way to do. Can string to be used for `NaN` value be forced at `stream` level, or better, at global level (using `std::locale` stuff?...never used that...).

I found this [squaring_num_put](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_put/put) example. Interesting because it's a way to modify a number is redirected to the output. But I'm having a hard time trying to adapt it to my problem (Could not make `do_put` send either a number or a hard coded "NaN" string to the `ostream`...).

Comment: *I need both to produce the same output*. Sounds like an XY problem to me...

Comment: Outputting of numbers ultimately calls [`std::num_put::do_put`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_put/put) which basically uses [`std::printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) to format the output. And as the [`std::printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) reference pages says, the output for NaN should be `nan` or `nan(char_sequence)`. (which one is implementation defined) This means that Visual Studio is wrong. It also means that even for compliant compilers and libraries, you have two alternative outputs to handle

Comment: So the question may be how to force VS2010 to output "nan" rather than "1.#QNAN"....nota that VS2015 follows the standard and outputs "nan", which is OK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might use a stream manipulator or modify the underlying locale:

Manipulator:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <ostream>

template <typename T>
struct FloatFormat
{
    const T value;

    FloatFormat(const T& value)
    : value(value)
    {}

    void write(std::ostream& stream) const {
        if(std::isnan(value))
            stream << "Not a Number";
        else
            stream << value;
    }
};

template <typename T>
inline FloatFormat<T> float_format(const T& value) {
    return FloatFormat<T>(value);
}

template <typename T>
inline std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& stream, const FloatFormat<T>& value) {
    value.write(stream);
    return stream;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << float_format(std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN()) << '\n';

}
```

Locale:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <locale>
#include <ostream>

template<typename Iterator = std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>>
class NumPut : public std::num_put<char, Iterator>
{
    private:
    using base_type = std::num_put<char, Iterator>;

    public:
    using char_type = typename base_type::char_type;
    using iter_type = typename base_type::iter_type;

    NumPut(std::size_t refs = 0)
    :   base_type(refs)
    {}

    protected:
    virtual iter_type do_put(iter_type out, std::ios_base& str, char_type fill, double v) const override {
        if(std::isnan(v))
            out = std::copy(std::begin(NotANumber), std::end(NotANumber), out);
        else
            out = base_type::do_put(out, str, fill, v);
        return out;
    }

    virtual iter_type do_put(iter_type out, std::ios_base& str, char_type fill, long double v) const override {
        if(std::isnan(v))
            out = std::copy(std::begin(NotANumber), std::end(NotANumber), out);
        else
            out = base_type::do_put(out, str, fill, v);
        return out;
    }

    private:
    static const char NotANumber[];
};

template<typename Iterator>
const char NumPut<Iterator>::NotANumber[] = "Not a Number";

#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() {
    #if 1
    {
        const std::size_t NoDestroy = 1;
        NumPut<> num_put(NoDestroy);
        std::locale locale(std::cout.getloc(), &num_put);
        std::locale restore_locale = std::cin.getloc();
        std::cout.imbue(locale);
        std::cout << std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN() << '\n';
        // The num_put facet is going out of scope:
        std::cout.imbue(restore_locale);
    }
    #else
    {
        // Alternitvely use a reference counted facet and pass the ownership to the locales:
        auto num_put = new NumPut<>();
        std::locale locale(std::cout.getloc(), num_put);
        std::cout.imbue(locale);
        std::cout << std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN() << '\n';
    }
    #endif
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

Just implement your own checking against the `quiet_NaN` value, and print based on that.

Comment: But you can't just use `== quiet_NaN` for that, NaNs never compare equal to anything (even themselves). It's one of their more interesting properties.

Comment: @MarkRansom: You can use `isnan`

Comment: @jpo38 I know that. I was prodding to get an improved answer.

Comment: @MarkRansom: you know, you can *edit* my answers to make them better ;)

Comment: @MarkRansom: or actually, you should've added that part of info to your Q in the first place ;)

Comment: I know how to test if a number is `nan`, but, obviously, for huge project where numbers are redirecting to outputs and files in many places, that will be a pain to add the test everywhere. I'm looking for a global solution (either modifiying `std::locale` or currently used `ostream` attributes).

Comment: I think your ostream attributes are pretty much the way to go; after all, what you want to do *is* modifying how specific things are printed.

Answer (score 2):

- Derive your `YourNumPut` from [std::num_put](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_put).
- Override what you need for example: `virtual iter_type do_put( iter_type out, std::ios_base& str, char_type fill, double v ) const;`
- Create locale that uses it: `std::locale yourLocale(std::locale(), new YourNumPut());`
- Set it global, imbue `cout` and `cerr` or where you need: `std::locale::global(yourLocale); std::cout.imbue(yourLocale); std::cerr.imbue(yourLocale);`
- Test it
- ...
- Profit ;)

Comment: I tried that, but could not figure out how to send a string (like "nan") to the output stream within `do_put` overloading method....could you please post a compiling example?

Comment: Just std::copy to out parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Use `isnan`() to portably test if a `double` is a NaN.

```
#include <cmath>

// ...

double d;

if (isnan(d))
   // ...
```

Comment: I know how to test if a number is `nan`, but, obviously, for huge project where numbers are redirecting to outputs and files in many places, that will be a pain to add the test everywhere. I'm looking for a global solution (either modifiying `std::locale` or currently used `ostream` attributes).

Answer (score 0):

In C++20 you'll be able to use [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format) to do this:

```
std::cout << std::format("{}", std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN());
```

This will print `nan` on all platforms that have `quiet_NaN`.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the author of C++20 `std::format`.