# What's wrong with std::nan/std::nanf under Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, c++11, nan

Wanted to play with [std::nan](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nan) and [std::nanf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nan) to create nan values with some custom payload (non boxing).

However, it really does not work as expected:

However, with Visual Studio 2015, the function apparently is not implemented right. The exact sample proposed by cppreference.com produces:

```
nan("1") = nan (7ff8000000000000)
nan("2") = nan (7ff8000000000000)
```

Which is not what we expect. Is VS implementation wrong? If not, what would be the right arguments to use to produce `7ff8000000000001` and `7ff8000000000002`?

Comment: First line in the reference: *"Converts the **implementation-defined** character string"*. This makes *"Is VS implementation wrong?"* vacuously answerable as no.

Comment: @StoryTeller: See your point. But what's the deal if it always returns the same value!?

Comment: Well, if you want a NaN value but you didn't pass the implementation defined sequence for a *specific* NaN, seems like pretty sane behavior. It's also the last line in the first paragraph of the same reference page.

Comment: "The exact sample proposed by cppreference.com produces" - That sample is followed by the phrase "Possible output"

Comment: "or zero if the implementation does not support quiet NaNs".  Yup, it never did.  It is only ever quiet when you don't have a 1-800 support phone number :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::nan` has, by definition, implementation-defined behavior, so VS is certainly not wrong as long as it returns some kind of quiet NaN.

In fact, the Microsoft docs have this to say:

> The `nan` functions return a floating-point value that corresponds to a quiet (non-signalling) NaN. **The input value is ignored**. For information about how a NaN is represented for output, see printf, _printf_l, wprintf, _wprintf_l.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/nan-nanf-nanl?view=vs-2017

This appears to be true (unsurprisingly), based on a small test:

```
std::nan("1") = 7ff8000000000000
std::nan("2") = 7ff8000000000000
std::nan("NAN(1)") = 7ff8000000000000
std::nan("NAN(2)") = 7ff8000000000000
std::nan("NAN1") = 7ff8000000000000
std::nan("NAN2") = 7ff8000000000000
std::nan("NAN 1") = 7ff8000000000000
std::nan("NAN 2") = 7ff8000000000000
```

Comment: That makes sense. They did things wrong (or the lazy way) but at least documented it ;-) Thanx!

Comment: @jpo38 Ironically, the link on that page ("For information about how a NaN is represented for output, see [printf, _printf_l, wprintf, _wprintf_l](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/printf-printf-l-wprintf-wprintf-l?view=vs-2017).") leads to a page that does not talk about NaNs...